# Why is chromatin not condensed during interphase but is in prophase

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology

Cell cycle goes through three processes:

- Interphase
- Mitosis
- Cytokinesis

Why are chromatins not condensed during interphase but instead condensed at prophase of mitosis? What makes them condense at prophase?

Comment: What resolution answer are you looking for here? Chromatin is complicated. If it was condensed during interphase, how would it be used? It would be folded up and inaccessible.

Comment: but then why is it condensed in prophase? and I still don't understand why are they condensed at prophase?

Comment: So that it can be partitioned neatly into daughter cells. If I understand correctly, your question boils down to "why is chromatin condensed at all?" ?

Comment: exactly. Also what makes them not condensed at Interphase?

Comment: This question is far too broad. From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the [help]: *"If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."* I suggest reading the Wikipedia article on [chromatin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatin) and the linked articles on, for example, the structure of DNA.

Comment: is there a brief explanation of the causes that lead to this process?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an image that explains the cell cycle:

[image]

And here's one that explains Mitosis as a subcategory of the cell cycle:

[image]

Chromosomes condense on the [metaphase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphase) plate before they are pulled apart by kinetochore microtubules in a *Tug-of-war*. Chromosome condensation is not yet fully understood, but [nucleosome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleosome) structure is hypothesized to play a role. This is a very good question and is definitely not too broad.